# Use special characters (åäö) in the PostgreSQL shell

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, shell

Been searching the web awhile now but can't find anything. I'm swedish and working with swedish words and terms in my database which makes me stumble upon loads of 'å, ä, ö' characters when importing data from different Excel-sheets. My question is if it at all matters if they become symbols, or if they're stored as the original character. And is it possible to have åäö showing in the shell?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4 and have in mind that I'm relatively new to the system.

Comment: Unicode?? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/multibyte.html

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, there are known issues with `psql`. Switch to the unicode codepage. See `chcp`.

Comment: Not sure what your question is: How do properly import Excel sheets so that the special characters show up? Or did you manage to do that, but the characters are not displayed correctly in the console?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I've imported the data from excel-sheets, but some rows contain 'åäö' which in the console is translated to symbols. I tried changing through PG-admin but it won't allow me. At the moment the encoding is UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

How they're treated by postgres will depend on the database encoding,
the client encoding, and if there is a conversion between that
postgres knows about.  The \encoding command in psql can be used
to show or set the client encoding.  The database encoding can be
seen by listing the databases with \l in psql There are other ways
to do either of those.

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html for more details.

In general, if you've got the client encoding set correctly for your input data, postgres will do the right thing.